# LCD not working after sudo update and upgrade

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

So I want to install opencv in my raspberry pi 3b. When I sudo update, upgrade and finally reboot my rasp pi, I noticed that my LCD touch is now disabled. Good thing I have a back-up of the OS to make the LCD touch enabled again. How will I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Before installing any new update in your Raspberry, check first provided drivers for your devices. Otherwise keep a copy of your drivers and reinstall them after update and upgrade.

Comment: Thanks but drivers were installed on the OS given by the manufacturer. I have also tried that thing but LCD touch is still disabled. I have also tried apt-mark hold kernel and bootloader but still doesn't work

Comment: then drivers binary are not suitable for the new update of  your OS. Try to read your driver description and compatibility